# What is the difference between Dice loss vs Jaccard loss in semantic segmentation task?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras, computer-vision

What is the difference between Dice loss vs Jaccard loss in semantic segmentation task?

Dice loss:

```
Dice = (2*|X & Y|)/ (|X|+ |Y|) =  2*sum(|A*B|)/(sum(A^2)+sum(B^2))

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    dice_coef = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + 
         K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return 1.0-dice_coef
```

Not sure why `Dice = (2*|X & Y|)/ (|X|+ |Y|) =  2*sum(|A*B|)/(sum(A^2)+sum(B^2))` ?

And seems implementation differ [here](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py#L27) & [here](https://gist.github.com/wassname/7793e2058c5c9dacb5212c0ac0b18a8a)

Jaccard loss:

```
Jaccard = (|X & Y|)/ (|X|+ |Y| - |X & Y|) = 
    sum(|A*B|)/(sum(|A|)+sum(|B|)-sum(|A*B|))

def jaccard_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    sum_ = K.sum(K.abs(y_true) + K.abs(y_pred), axis=-1)
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (sum_ - intersection + smooth)
    return (1 - jac) * smooth
```

[Jaccard.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/losses/jaccard.py)

Answer (score 1):

Jaccard Index is basically the Intersection over Union (IoU). If you subtract Jaccard Index from 1, you will get the Jaccard Loss (or IoU loss). Similarly if you do the same on Dice Coef., you will get the Dice Loss. For a comparison of IoU (or Jaccard) and Dice, I recommend reading [this](https://karan-jakhar.medium.com/100-days-of-code-day-7-84e4918cb72c) article.